# Hibernate diffChangeLog producing change sets that exist already in the table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am using spring boot with hibernate 5.3.8. After I run the first schema I generate a `diffChangeLog` and its dropping and creating the same index. When I look at the `collection_days` table a `common_collection_search` exists

How can I mark it as completed so it no longer appears in the diffChangeLog. I only want generate a changelog with the newest changes so I can run it and update the database

collection_days table

```
index_name|index_algorithm|is_unique|column_name|condition
common_collection_search|BTREE|f|waste_generator_id,refuse_type|NULL
```

This is from my master schema that I ran on a fresh database

```
  - changeSet:
      id: 1572649828026-46
      author: comp (generated)
      changes:
        - createIndex:
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: wg_id
              - column:
                  name: type
            indexName: common_collection_search
            tableName: collection_days
```

`diffChangeLog` results

```
  - changeSet:
      id: 1615578168770-16
      author: comp (generated)
      changes:
        - dropIndex:
            indexName: common_collection_search
            tableName: collection_days
  - changeSet:
      id: 1615578168770-17
      author: comp (generated)
      changes:
        - createIndex:
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: wg_id
              - column:
                  name: type
            indexName: common_collection_search
            tableName: collection_days
```

CollectionDay entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "collection_days", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "wg_id", "type", "day_of_week" }) }, indexes = {
        @Index(name = "common_collection_search", columnList = "wg_id,type") })
public class CollectionDay implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "wg_id",updatable = false,insertable = false)
  private Long wgId;

  @Column(name = "type")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private ESEnums.type type;
```

build.gradle

```
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-envers"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
compile "com.zaxxer:HikariCP"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5'
compile "org.postgresql:postgresql"
compile "org.liquibase:liquibase-core"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:6.1.6.Final"

liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:3.8'
liquibaseRuntime sourceSets.main.output
liquibaseRuntime sourceSets.main.compileClasspath

liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            driver 'org.postgresql.Driver'
            url 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:54323/db2?stringtype=unspecified'
            username ''
            password ''
            changeLogFile "src/main/resources/liquibase/migrations/changelog.yaml"
            classpath 'src/main/java'
            referenceUrl 'hibernate:spring:com.project.domain.entities?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that PostgreSQL is smart enough to realize that the index is unnecessary and doesn't create it in the way you expect it. Your unique constraint already covers the columns of the index and since it is backed by an index, it will just tell you that it won't create your index, because it is already covered.